# Redirect page after Submitting Form

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a form, which can either be submitted via AJAX or usual way, working with the **submit button**. The Ajax part is here:

```
parentForm.onsubmit = function(e) {                     // e represents trigering event
        if(srteValidateMode()){                             // works only in WYSIWYG mode
            var outputString = srteEditArea.innerHTML;      // first we prepare the text output data
            outputString = outputString                         
                    .replace(/<(\/?)strong>/gi, '<$1b>')    // unify output tags for all browsers -> B I P (instead of strong em div)
                    .replace(/<(\/?)em>/gi, '<$1i>')
                    .replace(/<(\/?)br>/gi, '<p>')
                    .replace(/<(\/?)div/gi, '<$1p');
            document.getElementById('simpleRTEoutput').value=outputString; // pass output string to hidden form field

            if (srteAjaxSubmit) {                           // ajax version - filling FormData
                e.preventDefault();                         // canceling the submit function - we will call it with Ajax
                var srteFormData = new FormData(e.target);  // getting form data from submitted form
                var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();     // now going to invoke AJAX

                ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200) {
                    srteShowInfo(ajaxRequest.responseText); // return message and display as info window
                    }
                }
                ajaxRequest.open("POST", e.target.action);  // getting target script from form action
                ajaxRequest.send(srteFormData);             // send FormData

            }
            else {                                          // Standard submit
                return true;                                // true = standard submit will proceed (works ok)
            }
        }
        else {return false;}                                // on false return form will not be submitted
        };
```

It works fine. Now I want to add redirection functionality - clicking on another (non submit) button with some onclick function to SAVE (do the predefined submit) AND redirect. I have such Idea (not tested), but not sure it this might work especially in the AJAX part.

```
function srteSubmitForm(redirectTo) {
    if (srteAjaxSubmit) {                   // redirect when submitted via Ajax Call
        parentForm.submit();                // save form data
        window.location.href = redirectTo;  // change location - does it wait for previous function ?
    }
    else {
        parentForm.action = parentForm.action + '?redirect=' + redirectTo; // rest handled by target PHP
        parentForm.submit();
    }
}
```

Button in HTML then would look like:

```
<input type="button" onclick="srteSubmitForm(\"somepage.php?page=A\")" value="Redirect A">
<input type="button" onclick="srteSubmitForm(\"somepage.php?page=B\")" value="Redirect B">
<input type="button" onclick="srteSubmitForm(\"somepage.php?page=C\")" value="Redirect C">
```

I am not sure, if I need to wait for the AJAX to be finished somehow before redirect ? Or any other way how redirect after the submit?

no jQuery solutions, please.
Thanks, Jan

Comment: If your going to redirect, why do you need ajax in the first place, and not just a regular form submit that redirects by default.

Comment: I want Ajax to save the form while working on the form content (article). But also want to add buttons for simple links (list of articles, preview, etc) - and so I want to save (post via ajax) and redirect. Maybe my idea of proper solution is not the best one, I just cant think of any other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not add a 'callback' parameter to your submit method that gets called when the call completes.

```
parentForm.submit(function(status){
    //The call completed, you can display a confirm message 'Form submitted, 
    //now redirecting' (because it's not nice to redirect without warning ;)
    window.location.href = redirectTo;
});
```

And in your submit:

```
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200) {
        srteShowInfo(ajaxRequest.responseText);
        if(callback instanceof Function) callback(ajaxRequest.responseText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Frederic, it takes me some time to understand (not really familiar with callbacks), but I think I'm roughly getting the point. Just not sure about the last line - the "callback" function needs to be defined somewhere?

Comment: I made a simple fiddle and cant make it working, could you point me the right direction ? [http://jsfiddle.net/Ry9zA/](http://jsfiddle.net/Ry9zA/)

Comment: I've taken the essence of what you are trying to do and made this quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/7LBAR/